# Is the Fifa'a language of Saudi Arabia a dialect of Arabic or a separate language?

Tags: dialects, arabic, semitic-languages, language-isolates

A Saudi friend on our sister site, travel.stackexchange.com, was just telling me there is an isolated language in his country called "Fifa'a", but that nothing is written about it on the internet as far as he can find.

I also can't find any information on it. But it seems to have some other spellings: Fayfa, Faifa, etc.

He mentioned that some people regard it as a dialect of Arabic but others do not. He tells me it has a similar sound to Arabic but a totally different grammar.

Is Fifa'a a dialect of Arabic? Where can I even read anything about it?

Comment: In the gulf war, Saudi Army radio operators were from Fifa'a area, only to use this [language/dialect] to communicate. I am an Arab and I can tell you, if you are not from Fifa'a you will never understand it..

Comment: @Flyer Unfortunately, mutual intelligibility is not a criteria for defining a language/dialect. As I assume you know, there are lots of Arabic speakers that have trouble understanding one another and that's all one "language". Do you happen to know any textbooks or historical records involving Fifa'a or the region where it's spoken? Anything that could help us establish how the language evolved.

Comment: I found two relevant discussions on the topic. [This discussion about duals forms](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1945107) and [this discussion on the linguistic diversity in Saudi Arabia/Yemen](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1747810). The same user in both threads claims Fayfa is Himyaric while others argue it is Arabic. Unfortunately, neither side offers much proof.

Comment: It's the language of football!

Comment: @acattle Actually mutual intelligibility *is* the usual criterion in linguistics for defining a language/dialect. Dialects are mutually intelligible varieties of a language. Different languages are varieties that are *not* mutually intelligible. Of course, this is the technical usage of 'language/dialect' within linguistics; there are certainly other uses (eg political) that would define the terms differently.

Comment: @acattle Just to add, this does not mean it's easy to determine whether two varieties are dialects or different languages, given such issues as one-way intelligibility. dialect chains/nets, etc.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut The quote I see a lot is that "A language is a dialect with an army and a navy". From my understanding it's a purely political distinction and, to a linguist, almost meaningless. What I was getting at with my comment was that without historical context for how Fayfa developed we can't establish relatedness, let alone a dialect/language distinction.

Comment: @acattle Well yes, but the terms 'language' and 'dialect' have specific meanings within linguistics. Have a look at the entry for 'language' in [glottopedia](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Language), particularly the third paragraph, which contrasts the standard, technical usage of 'language' and 'dialect' in linguistics with the non-technical usage.

Comment: @acattle and OP, the question of Fayfa being a dialect of Arabic or a separate language is not well-posed. 'Arabic' covers a group of varieties which includes different languages even tho it's often referred to as tho it's a single language (unified by a standard form, Classical Arabic, and a common writing system). For example, Moroccan Arabic is not mutually intelligible with Levantine Arabic, so is a distinct language. Perhaps the question should ask if Fayfa is a dialect of Saudi Arabic?

Comment: I don't agree. Yes questions of language vs dialect outside linguistics are fraught with problems, but within linguistics it's mostly down to mutual comprehensibility plus a little bit of standardization/orthography on top sometimes. I'm happy for an answer that tells me it's mutually comprehensible with any Arabic variety deemed a language. My Saudi friend assures me that other Arabs can't understand it. Is Saudi Arabic a language by this definition? I was pretty sure it was mutually comprehensible with Arabic spoken in neighbouring countries.

Comment: Hi Hippie, who are you not agreeing with? Re Saudi Arabic, it's quite mutually intelligible with other neigbouring Arabics, but not with the Western Arabic varieties (Libya to Morroco and nearby countries). Anyway, I've written an answer, hope it's ok.

Comment: Sorry I didn't spot the typo in my question title! I wrote "of Saudi Arabic" when I meant "of Saudi Arabia".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fayfa dialect is certainly not Mahri or even remotely related to it.  Mahri is spoken hundreds of miles away in the far eastern regions of Yemen and the neighboring parts of Oman (along with a few related language and dialects, collectively referred to as Modern South Arabian).  Modern South Arabian is a distinct langauge family in the Semitic group that is not closely related to Arabic.  Its closest relatives are in Ethiopia and Eritrea.

Fayfa is in the southwest corner of Saudi Arabia. Because people from other regions find it difficult to understand, there is a common belief that it is descended from the Old South Arabian languages of ancient Yemen such as Himyaritic or Sabaic, but this is not based on any academic source.  In fact, its dialect is genetically part of Arabic (whether or not you consider it a separate language based on mutual intelligibility is a separate issue) and can be largely understood by other Arabic speakers when transcribed in writing, albeit influenced to some extent by a South Arabian substrate. Many of its "strange" features (such as the definite article "am-") are found in many other Arabic dialects of that region. A detailed analysis can be found [here](https://sarkhasi.wordpress.com/2020/07/12/are-faifi-and-or-razihit-descendants-of-ancient-south-arabian-spoiler-alert-no/).

Comment: Hi and thanks, looks like my answer from 7 years ago was incorrect! I see there is also now a WP page on [Fayfa/Faifi language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faifi_language).

Comment: Hippietrail, feel free to unaccept my answer...

Comment: Since Mehri is Semitic, it is obviously at *least* remotely related to Fayfi.

Comment: It being an Old South Arabian language is based on an academic source. The grammar cited on the wikipedia page linked above for instance gives it as a result of "hypercontact" between Sabaic and Classical Arabic. Whether that would make it a highly divergent variety of Arabic proper, or a Sayhadic variety greatly assimilated to Arabic is open to interpretation, but it's clear that there is still *some* academic basis for classifying it as Sayhadic

Comment: @user6726 I should have said not particularly related to it. My point is that they are from separate branches of the Semitic tree.

Comment: @Tristan the source is a master’s thesis that doesn’t affirmatively say it is Sayhadic but only raises the possibility. And it only compares Fayfi to Classical Arabic when it should be comparing it to neighboring Arabic dialects. The post I linked to explains this and other issues with his approach.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, I'm just saying that "not based on any academic source" is overstating the case

Answer (score 6):

There isn't much information on the language referred to by the OP as "Fifa'a", but there is some information on a group of people in Saudi Arabia called the Fayfa. The Fayfa are described [in this evangelical religious website](http://www.peoplegroups.org/Explore/groupdetails.aspx?peid=42795) as speaking Mehri. Additionally, the [Missionary Atlas Project](http://worldmap.org/maps/other/profiles/saudi%20arabia/Saudi%20Arabia.pdf) lists the "Fayfa" people and also describes them as speaking Mehri. This makes it likely that this is the language the OP (based on his informant) refers to as "Fifa'a" so I proceed on this assumption.

The Fayfa people of Saudia Arabia speak Mehri, a [Yemeni language](http://www.ethnologue.com/language/gdq) classified as a member of the [South Arabian subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehri_language) of the South Semitic group of languages (within the Semitic branch of the Afro-Asiatic family). The Arabic languages (which includes Saudi Arabic), on the other hand, are classified within the Central Semitic group (etc) so are quite distantly related to Mehri. This means that Arabic and Fayfa are definitely not mutually intelligible and can therefore be described as distinct languages.

The majority of Mehri speakers are in Yemen, but there are also a number in Oman. There is a modest body of work on Mehri, some of which is listed at [OLAC](http://www.language-archives.org/language/gdq).

Comment: It looks like you found it! (-:

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, but I think [this](http://northwiththecatpeople.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/i-was-invited-by-fellow-teacher-to-go.html) is about a trip to the same place, but spelled 'Faifa'.

Comment: Yes I doubt *Fifa'a* is even a written language and my Saudi friend tells me the country's government is not interested in its minority peoples so I don't even know if it has a standard spelling in Arabic let alone English. Just writing standard Arabic in the English alphabet results in lots of variations as it is ...

Comment: I'm never sure what people mean when they say 'written language', but if you follow my OLAC link you'll see there are materials in Mehri which would have required an orthography. Most speakers are in Yemen, maybe they're more helpful to minorities?

Comment: [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehri_language): It is primarily a spoken language, with little existing vernacular literature and almost no literacy in the written form among native speakers.

Comment: Yes, it's a very strange description: 'primarily a spoken language'--All human languages are primarily spoken (or signed); 'little [...] vernacular literature'--what other sort of literature would there be in a language except 'vernacular'!; 'almost no literacy in the written form...'--what other sort of literacy is there?

Comment: I agree but all linguists know that few non-linguists seem to think this way. I think the only way to read it is not so literally. "It has a greater ratio of speech to writing than European etc languages" / "Very little literature in this speech variety compared to Arabic". For the third point the sensible reading is that there exists ***[oral literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_literature)***.

Comment: Hey, I agree, but I think your explanation is very linguistically informed, and non-linguists would typically be hard-pressed to come to that level of understanding. And I've never liked the term 'oral literature', in my view it conflates two very different things, but I know I'm in the minority!

Comment: BTW @hippietrail, the reason I go on about this is my experience that the jump from illiteracy to literacy is really quite small and easy if a language has a good orthography. Oops, better stop now, getting the 'move to chat' message. cheers!

Comment: Yes when we hit the "edge" of the Internet though the information gets a bit rough or vague so we have to make do with what we've got. In this case a less than perfect Wikipedia but modulated through some Stack Exchange linguistics expertise. Maybe some better info will come along later ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Fayfa people. Our language is an old Arabic language, kholane language.

All the people around our area have similar languages but a little different, and understand our language and we understand theirs, and understand modern Arabic language.

Comment: I tried to fix spelling and punctuation, but I had to guess a few things. Do you mean you call your language Kholane? (Can you explain how to pronounce this? Like kho lan eh with a pharyngeal consonant at the beginning? Like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%B8%AA%C4%81%CA%BE ?)